# Issue with Wordpress customize

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, theme-customizer

I am usign Hello Elemntor Child Theme. I am changing woocommerce product thumbnail size. it change in customize preview but when i see it on front end or i refresh the customize page, changes get rolled back. Here is what i want.

[image]

And here is what it turns when i refresh customize page.

[image]

this issue is coming on live server only. working fine on localhost. i am using hostinger as server

Comment: changing the size and cropping options for an image size does not regenerate the image sizes for already uploaded files, those only work for newly uploaded items. Otherwise you need to ask Elementor theme support for help with their products

Comment: it is not letting me change anything. when i publish after changing them and reload page or customizer i get what i previously had (i.e. no changes)

Comment: it should at least let me change and save things.

Comment: that sounds like a bug in the theme, you should let them know and make sure you're up to date, 3rd party product support questions are off topic here